# AWS Lambda extensions: throws LaunchError

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to create a sample lambda extension by following the steps mentioned in the document - https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lambda-extensions/tree/main/python-example-extension

But I am getting the below error

```
{
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: 751694e2-022b-484d-8bbc-29d3bde52cf5 Error: fork/exec /opt/extensions/python-example-extension: no such file or directory",
  "errorType": "Extension.LaunchError"
}
```

Could you please help?

Comment: The error mention that the folder python-example-extension is missing.
you need to include it in the zip folder before running the sam build command

Answer (score 0):

The error means that there is no file with that name in the lambda's file system.
Maybe you packed the layer wrong?

My tip about the file structure with layers: the zip of the layer is being decompressed into `/opt`.

Therefore, in order for you to have the directory "extensions" and a file "python-example-extension" inside it, you need to have this directory in the zip that you're uploading as a layer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try setting the EOL of the extensions/python-example-extension to LF. Worked for me.